# Jenkins/groovy: How to pretty-print a net.sf.json.JSONObject with null?

Tags: json, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

Working on a Jenkins pipeline, I observed what looks like infinite recursion causing a stack overflow when I use `JsonOutput.toJson()` on a `net.sf.json.JSONObject` that slurped a JSON string containing null.

The following minimal code demonstrates the problem:

```
// Jenkinsfile
@Library('libs@dev') libs

import groovy.json.JsonOutput

pipeline {
  agent any

  stages {
    stage( "json" ) {
      steps {
        script {
          my_lib.to_json_handbuilt_linkedhashmap()
          my_lib.to_json_readjson()
          my_lib.to_json_readjson_as_linkedhashmap()
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```
// vars/my_lib.groovy
import groovy.json.JsonOutput

def asMap(j) {
  return j as LinkedHashMap
}

// This function is successful.
def to_json_handbuilt_linkedhashmap() {
  def d = [:]
  d.issues = null

  echo "---- handmade LinkedHashMap ----"
  echo "d ${d}"
  echo "d.getClass() ${d.getClass()}"
  echo "JsonOutput.toJson(d) ${JsonOutput.toJson(d)}"
}

// This function fails from infinite recursion causing a stack overflow.
def to_json_readjson() {
  def d = readJSON(text: '{ "issues" : null }')

  echo "---- readJSON ----"
  echo "d ${d}"
  echo "d.getClass() ${d.getClass()}"
  echo "JsonOutput.toJson(d) ${JsonOutput.toJson(d)}"
}

// This function also fails from infinite recursion causing a stack overflow.
def to_json_readjson_as_linkedhashmap() {
  def d = asMap(readJSON(text: '{ "issues" : null }'))

  echo "---- readJSON -> asMap ----"
  echo "d ${d}"
  echo "d.getClass() ${d.getClass()}"
  echo "JsonOutput.toJson(d) ${JsonOutput.toJson(d)}"
}
```

In the code above, `to_json_readjson()` fails with a stack overflow when `JsonOutput.toJson()` is called with the `net.sf.json.JSONObject` returned by `readJSON(text: '{ "issues" : null }')`.
The Jenkins console output is at the end of this post.

In `to_json_handbuilt_linkedhashmap()` `JsonOutput.toJson()` is successful when called with a handcrafted `LinkedHashMap` equivalent to `{ "issues" : null }`.

Lastly, in `to_json_readjson_as_linkedhashmap()`, `JsonOutput.toJson()` again fails with a stack overflow when called with a `LinkedHashMap` created from a `net.sf.json.JSONObject`.

**Question:**
**Can someone please explain what's causing the stack overflow when `readJSON()` and/or `JsonOutput.toJson()` are used with a JSON string that has `null`?**

Because my handcrafted `LinkedHashMap` was successful with `JsonOutput.toJson()`, I thought the problem was passing `JsonOutput.toJson()` a `net.sf.json.JSONObject`.
But I think that theory is ruled out because in `to_json_readjson_as_linkedhashmap()`, I give `JsonOutput.toJson()` a `LinkedHashMap`, albeit created from a `net.sf.json.JSONObject`.
The problem would appear to be some combination of `readJSON()` and/or `JsonOutput.toJson()` that I'm failing to grasp.

I tried, but have given up trying to use a `JsonSlurper`, because [I'm unable to even create an instance of one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71058274/why-does-instantiating-a-jsonslurper-cause-not-serializable-exception).

The (truncated) stack overflow error likely showing infinite recursion:

```
Posting build status of FAILED to bitbucket.company.comjava.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.io.PrintStream.flush(PrintStream.java:338)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:297)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:141)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:229)
    at java.util.logging.StreamHandler.flush(StreamHandler.java:259)
    at java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.publish(ConsoleHandler.java:117)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.log(Logger.java:738)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.doLog(Logger.java:765)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.throwing(Logger.java:1447)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.getProperties(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:391)
    at groovy.json.JsonOutput.getObjectProperties(JsonOutput.java:327)
    at groovy.json.JsonOutput.writeObject(JsonOutput.java:320)
    at groovy.json.JsonOutput.writeMap(JsonOutput.java:458)
    at groovy.json.JsonOutput.writeObject(JsonOutput.java:321)
    at groovy.json.JsonOutput.writeMap(JsonOutput.java:458)
    at groovy.json.JsonOutput.writeObject(JsonOutput.java:321)
    at groovy.json.JsonOutput.writeMap(JsonOutput.java:458)
    at groovy.json.JsonOutput.writeObject(JsonOutput.java:321)
    at groovy.json.JsonOutput.writeMap(JsonOutput.java:458)
    at groovy.json.JsonOutput.writeObject(JsonOutput.java:321)
    at groovy.json.JsonOutput.writeMap(JsonOutput.java:458)
    at groovy.json.JsonOutput.writeObject(JsonOutput.java:321)
    at groovy.json.JsonOutput.writeMap(JsonOutput.java:458)
    at groovy.json.JsonOutput.writeObject(JsonOutput.java:321)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you sidestep this immediate problem by using `readJSON`'s `returnPojo: true` parameter, thereby solving your overall task sooner?

Getting plain old `null`s rather than net.sf.json.JSONNull objects really helped me today, though my problem involved producing CSV rather than using JsonOutput.

Comment: Thank you for clueing me in to the `returnPojo` field -- I'd not realized that was an option, and yes: it appears to solve this cleanly and perfectly.